# XML DTD Namespace not Bound

Tags: xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces, dtd

OK, so I need to declare namespaces for an XML project, and validate using DTD.  Everything seems correct, even my friends and professor say so, but I keep getting an error message saying "The prefix "st" for element "st:course" is not bound."  It looks bound to me, what am I missing?

XML:

```
<?xml-namespace ns="http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns" prefix="st"?>
<?xml-namespace ns="http://www.student_courses/data/cr/ns" prefix="cr"?>
<!DOCTYPE students SYSTEM "student_courses.dtd">

<students>
<student number="a101"> <!-- number is an ID, required-->
<Name title="Mr.">John Doe</Name><!-- title values can be 'Mr.','Ms.','Dr.'-->
<st:course xmlns= "http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns" section="01">WEB 225</st:course>
<enrolled>22</enrolled>

<content>
<level class="Intro"></level>
<comments>Great course</comments><!-- An optional element -->
<book isbn="">XML</book><!--isbn is required, but the element is optional -->
</content>
</student>

<student number="a102"><!-- number is an ID, required-->
<Name title="Dr.">Jane Williams</Name>
<st:course xmlns= "http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns">WEB 325</st:course>
<enrolled>22</enrolled>

<content>
<level class="Adv."></level>
</content>
</student>

<student number="a103"><!-- number is an ID, required-->
<Name title="Ms.">Jane Doe</Name><!-- title values can be 'Mr.','Ms.','Dr.'-->
<st:course xmlns= "http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns" section="03">WEB  440</st:course>
<enrolled>12</enrolled>

<content>
<level class="Adv."></level>
<comments>Great course</comments><!-- An optional element -->
</content>
</student>

<courses>

<cr:course xmlns = "http://www.student_courses/data/cr/ns" id="WEB225">
<name>Web Development II</name>
<offered>Spring</offered>
<pre_reqs>WEB125</pre_reqs>
</cr:course>

<cr:course xmlns = "http://www.student_courses/data/cr/ns" id="WEB125">
<name>Web Development I</name>
<offered>Fall</offered>
</cr:course>

<cr:course xmlns = "http://www.student_courses/data/cr/ns" id="WEB325">
<name>Client-Side Scripting</name>
<offered>Spring</offered>
<offered>Fall</offered>
<pre_reqs>WEB225</pre_reqs>
</cr:course>

</courses>

</students>
```

And here is my DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT students (student+)>
<!ELEMENT student (Name+,st:course+,enrolled+,content+)>
<!ATTLIST student number ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Name title (Mr. | Ms. | Dr.) #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT st:course (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST st:course xmlns CDATA #FIXED "http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns"> 
<!ATTLIST st:course section CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT enrolled (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT content (level+, comments*, book?)>
<!ELEMENT level (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST level class (Intro | Adv.) #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT comments (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT book (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST book isbn CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT courses (cr:course+)>
<!ELEMENT cr:course (name+,offered+,pre_reqs*)>
<!ATTLIST cr:course xmlns:cr CDATA #FIXED "http://www.student_courses/data/cr/ns"> 
<!ATTLIST cr:course id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT offered (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pre_reqs (#PCDATA)>
```

Thanks everyone, love this place!!

-K

Comment: Note that I haven't found 'xml-namespace' processing instruction anywhere in the official w3c specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem ares are:

1. In DTD change <!ATTLIST st:course xmlns CDATA #FIXED "http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns">  to <!ATTLIST st:course xmlns:st CDATA #FIXED "http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns">
2. In XML comment your  <courses>... </courses> element as it is not valid as per your DTD. Your DTD has <student> under <students> only.
3. Change in XML everywhere <st:course xmlns= "http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns"...> to <st:course xmlns:st="http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns"...>
4. At the starting of XML change <?xml-namespace ns="http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns" prefix="st"?> to <?xml-namespace st="http://www.student_courses/data/st/ns" prefix="st"?>

First and third one is corelated to each other. If you want to keep your 'course' element as 'st:course' (with namespace prefix) then you must delcare it into your DTD.

Where Second and Third are self explenatory.

Comment: I don't understand your second point:  Courses is another element, and I need the cr namespace to avoid a name collision with the course element there and in the student element.  Everything else you have makes sense to me though.

Comment: As per your created DTD you have only one child element student under root element students. But if you want to add one more child element - 'courses', you must change your DTD from &lt;!ELEMENT students (student+)&gt; to &lt;!ELEMENT students (student+,courses)&gt;. And in your XML change &lt;cr:course xmlns = "http://www.student_courses/data/cr/ns"...&gt; to &lt;cr:course xmlns:cr = "http://www.student_courses/data/cr/ns"...&gt;